# Is Corporatocracy a result of Corporatism?

Tags: democracy, capitalism, corporations

The way I understand it so far (and I could be wrong so fact-checking appreciated): capitalism can lead to corporatism, which can lead to corporatocracy? The nuances are tricky and have lots of historical overlap. Really just looking at the processes here and how capitalism evolves.

Comment: Is there evidence for corporatism & corporatocracy being anything but buzzwords used as propaganda by the left?

Comment: Corporations are ultimately still owned als controlled by groups of people. The formality isn't the issue, it's age old balance of power between social strata divided by wealth. Protesting "corporations" is IMO just a modern day verbal shorthand used in place of 19th and early-mid 20th century vocabulary of class conflict.

Comment: No offense meant here, and welcome aboard, but could you clarify exactly what you mean by this terminology?  What is corporatism?  What is corporatocracy?  How do they differ from plain old capitalism and [regulatory capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulatory_capture) and/or [oligarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oligarchy)?

Comment: @Pete W: But one of the defining factors of the corporation is that people do not need to be wealthy (or at least not extremely so) in order to own parts of it.  Indeed, vechicles like IRA/401k plans (in the US) allow people to become modestly wealthy via corporate ownership.

Comment: @jamesqf - How widespread that is in practice would make a good question, perhaps. I suspect the same sentiments would, to a degree, be aimed at the top 10-20%, or whatever the figure is who, in western countries, enjoy 'modestly wealthy' levels of savings by way of capital appreciation. Not because they are exercising control in the style of the JP Morgan's or Andrew Carnegie's of old, but because they are (on the whole) going along for the ride and lending the larger pattern of distribution an air of inevitability -- and often standing aside when there are calls for more taxation of capital.

Comment: @Pete W: Like anything else, it only works if you use it.  And of course you need to remember that many of the modestly wealthy are that because of gradual accumulation over their working life. But if you exclude stocks held by foreign investors, the majority of US stocks are owned by retirement funds of one sort or another.  (And these probably hold a good bit of foreign stock as well.)

Comment: Corporatism has two entirely separate meanings: [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporatism) linked with Italian fascism and Roman Catholic social teaching based around guilds and other societies, and the other perhaps better called [corporatocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporatocracy) or corporate capitalism, rule by corporations in a capitalist society.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitionally speaking, Corporatism and Corporatocracy are the same thing - it's simply a matter of whether or not the control by private, for-profit interests is explicit in the law.

-ocracy is the suffix to indicate an official, legal, and deliberate structure. Democracy (Demos, the people + 'ocracy' = Government by the people), only truly exists where it is codified to be so in law.  A king who defers all of his rulings to a popular referendum is still a king. It's a *de facto* democracy, but *de jure* monarchy - and as such the king can always change his mind. (The hand that giveth, may taketh away.) To my knowledge, Corporatocracy only exists in fiction.

Corporatism refers to a state of affairs in which the control of the government is *NOT* explicit in law, and arises either through skullduggery/conspiracy (commonly the case in fiction), or as an emergent property of political systems.

Capitalism isn't entirely unrelated to either, but is not sufficient cause for either (and arguably not even necessary for either, but that seems very in the philosophical weeds).

In order for Corporatism to arise, you require private interests to be able to amass political power that exceeds the political power of the government.  Fear of this is part of the reasoning behind things like anti-trust laws, which break up monopolies so that a corporation cannot fully become a government (dictator, really) in and of itself.  There are other ways, beyond gobs and gobs of money, to amass political power, however.  The NRA is not a for-profit company, but had no problem amassing political power.  For a less politically charged example, ask your elected representative in the United States if they'd ever turn down a call from the AARP.

It's important to note that corporatism doesn't require for-profit companies, either; the NRA and AARP are both non-profit NGOs.

Nothing about capitalism - a socioeconomic system where property rights exist and the economy is predominately organized by market forces of price, supply, and demand - requires either Corporatism or Corporatocracy.  In fact, in order for capitalism to remain healthy, either of those states must be avoided as they both distort market outcomes and thereby render markets inefficient.

So, to review:

Capitalism is a socioeconomic system where property rights are protected by law, and citizens may dispose of their property freely; economic outcomes are largely dictated by market forces ideally in free markets. (Note that the definition of 'free market' is it's own barrel of worms.)

Corporatism is a condition where political outcomes are *de facto* dictated by private interests outside the official government.

Corporatocracy is a government where, *de jure*, corporations are the lawmakers and decisionmakers of the government itself.

Capitalism *can*, but *does not have to*, lead to Corporatism or Corporatocracy. So for example, in the United States, to the extent that Corporatism exists it is far more the fault of the 'first past the post,' plurality system that U.S. elections are built upon than it is capitalism; though the latter may act as a catalyst on the process. Making these determinations is, obviously, an exercise for the observer.

Comment: You wrote: "To my knowledge, Corporatocracy only exists in fiction." But it has existed e.g. with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanseatic_League

Comment: @ThomasKoelle I wondered about something like that, but lack the History chops to make the call myself.  But I love the example. I deliberately went with the present-tense for that reason. (Stuff like OPEC pushes the limits even there.)

Comment: Do you have an explanation for why corporatism in the US is caused more by FPTP than capitalism?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco The tl;dr version is this: First past the post gives disproportionate political power to the winners of elections in the U.S.  In parliamentary systems, minority voices still have seats.  This means that winning the advertisement war, which is basically a money race, is enough to entirely lockout your opposition. This, in turn, makes candidates decidedly more incentivized to cater to deep pocketed donors.